# the custom header view in my UITableView draws extra lines at bottom

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image: Custom header looks good in InterfaceBuilder.][image]

I'm having trouble with a custom header in my UITableView.

In InterfaceBuilder, I'm creating a XIB file with a view, and then subclassing it to UITableViewHeaderFooterView. I'm adding in some subviews. Nothing special.

In my viewDidLoad routine, I'm calling "registerNib:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier".

Then, in my delegate method, tableView:viewForHeaderInSection, I'm calling:

```
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView* theView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"header"];
```

The weird thing, is that I'm getting some extra lines of graphic, at the bottom edge of my header. It actually looks like the "normal" header view peeking through. I have no idea how to fix this. I've checked the size of the header view, vs the height of the section header. I've also put in code to force the size of the section-header to be the same as the the view's height. Yet, I still can't explain this.

The thing to notice, in the "Simulator - Bad" image is the gray color in between my custom header, and the red area. The red area is my first cell. So there are these gray lines that aren't in my custom header, nor in my first cell.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you returning the correct height in your `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` delegate call?

Comment: yes. It's the same height as the view in my XIB, in this case, 42.

Comment: OK, well I still don't know why this is happening, but I've given up. Even though I'm absolutely certain that my view should be 42 points high, I decided to just change the value to 38. This chops off the gray space at the bottom. It doesn't seem like I should have to do this, and still don't get it. But I spent to much time trying to diagnose this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the height of your section header? Like so:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 40.0;  // or whatever your header's height is
}
```